# ShowMessage apresenta a mensagem 2 vezes

Tags: delphi

Possuo o seguinte codigo abaixo:

```
 for i := 1 to form1.variavel do
        with form1 do
       if TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Text = '' then
        begin
         showmessage ('Preencha os campos em branco')
        end
        else
 form2.showmodal;
```

ele verifica se existem campos em branco e mostra uma mensagem se existir.

Na aplicação ele mostra a mensagem 2 vezes, ele mostra `Preencha os campos em branco`, clico em ok e ele repete a mesma mensagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problemas está no seu for, está passando 2 vezes, assim mostrando 2 mensagens;
Faça da seguinte maneira:

```
boolean existeCamposVazio := false;

for i := 1 to form1.variavel do begin

       if TEdit(FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Text = '' then begin
         existeCamposVazio = true;
         break;
       end;
 end;      

 if (existeCamposVazio) then
     showmessage ('Preencha os campos em branco');
   end else begin 
      with form1 do
     form2.showmodal;
   end;
```

Espero ter ajudado.